# 2D Infinite Runner: how to manage the generation of dynamic terrain?

Tags: c#, side-scroller, unity

I'm creating a infinite runner game with Unity3d, i've been using math to generate the terrain by calculating the size/pos of the terrain and place the new one next to it, and it's working correctly, but i think it's a overkill, so the question is, Is there a better way(performance) to generate terrain/floor in 2d scrolling infinite runners?

I also tried this method which consist of using empty gameobject, and when you hit them it create the terrain it was okay, but then problem started when i started using different terrain generation

Comment: You question is difficult to answer specifically.  What solution would not be overkill?  How good does the performance need to be, and how bad is it now?  You encountered a problem switching from your previous method to your current method, but you didn't say what the problem is.  Please consult the [help] about how to phrase a question to get the best chance of helpful answers.  Currently your question is essentially open-ended, which on this SE is a reason for it to be closed.

Comment: It is not, i just want to know what method some people have used to generate the terrain.

Comment: Polling for examples other people have done to implement a thing isn't a good fit for this site.

Comment: Dude, the purpose of this page is to ask for help, also my question fit, because i've tried my things. @JoshPetrie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the player is alive, you can increase the offset of the texture. Basically the player stays still and the texture moves. Little cheating in this method as it takes around 20 lines of code and isn't fancy.

Comment: Sometimes simplicity works best.